# Is a matching receiver module needed in order to use a Bluetooth audio transmitter/transceiver/emitter module?

Tags: audio, bluetooth

[image]

I'm using this audio Bluetooth emitter.

[image]

I connected it like so, the LED flashes, but no Bluetooth device is displayed on my phone or PC. How do I troubleshoot this or do I need a matching receiver module?

Comment: We don't know what module that is so we can't say if it can work with any receiver or does it require a custom receiver. What does the manual say?

Comment: https://github.com/Mark-MDO47/BluetoothAudioTransmitter_KCX_BT_EMITTER looks to be a GitHub repository which shows a picture of the same module. The README contains ``This Bluetooth Module uses an "AT" command set to program it to connect to your speaker and not others. `` which suggests you need to send command commands via the UART TX/RX pins to pair with the speakers. I haven't checked the manual.

Comment: Have you paired the module with your phone and / or PC? For that to happen, the device needs to be put in discovery mode, read the manual.

Comment: There is no manual. I'll see about using AT commands from that repo. Thank you.

Comment: Looks like https://www.electro-tech-online.com/threads/kcx_bt_emitter-low-cost-bluetooth-bt-audio-module.158156/ has some more information on the AT commands for this module.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, and no AT commands are needed for this to connect. The connection pin (`CON`) on the module may (or may not) be need to pair to a Bluetooth receiver.